# For loop not working correctly in Rock Paper Scissors Java program

Tags: java, loops

I'm new to programming and have been attempting to code a simple Rock Paper Scissors game in Java, but I'm stuck with two problems. The game worked correctly prior to me adding a for loop in order to make the game last for 5 rounds each time, but now with the loop it just repeats the same result line 4 times after entering 1 input, rather than allowing me to enter more inputs and generate several results. I also tried putting in an invalid input message, where if the user inputs anything other than 1, 2 or 3 the program outputs "Invalid user input.", but this doesn't work when ran and has just resulted in compiler error messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the entirety of my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static final int ROCK = 1;
    public static final int PAPER = 2;
    public static final int SCISSORS =3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors! (best out of 5)");

        System.out.println("Enter either 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberGuessed = input.nextInt();

        Random generator = new Random();
        int computerNumber = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;

        for (int round = 0; round < 4; round++) {
            if (numberGuessed == computerNumber) {
            System.out.print("It's a tie!");
        }

        if (numberGuessed == 1 && computerNumber == 2) {
            System.out.println("You lose! I chose paper and paper smothers rock!");
        }
        else if (numberGuessed == 1 && computerNumber == 3) {
            System.out.println("You win! I chose scissors and rock smashes scissors!");
        }
        else if (numberGuessed == 2 && computerNumber == 1) {
            System.out.println("You win! I chose rock and paper smothers rock!");
        }
        else if (numberGuessed == 2 && computerNumber == 3) {
            System.out.println("You lose! I chose scissors and scissors cut paper!");
        }
        else if (numberGuessed == 3 && computerNumber == 2) {
            System.out.println("You win! I chose paper and scissors cut paper!");
        }
        else if (numberGuessed == 3 && computerNumber == 1) {
            System.out.println("You lose! I chose rock and rock smashes scissors!");
        }
        else if (numberGuessed != 1 || numberGuessed != 2 || numberGuessed != 3) {
            System.out.println("Invalid user input.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might just be a formatting error but if it's not, you should always indent code within brackets to signify tiers.

Comment: The input and random number generation happen outside the for loop. This means these numbers are set and will not change. Maybe put them inside the for loop and see how you get on.

Comment: @bbnumber2 are you referring to the if statements? I'll fix that now, thanks!

Comment: @Anna79 Yes. Since all of the if statements are within your for loop they should all be indented one tier past the loop's tier. All of the code in the if statements should be indented one tier further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have not ended all of the curly braces properly which is leading to compiler error.
- `for (int round = 0; round < 4; round++)` will end for upto 4 rounds, for 5 rounds of loop the condition can be like this: `for (int round = 0; round < 5; round++)`
- The for loop should start before the input is taken each time so that it can process each input separately.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class RockPaperScissors {

    public static final int ROCK = 1;
    public static final int PAPER = 2;
    public static final int SCISSORS = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors! (best out of 5)");

        for (int round = 0; round < 5; round++) {
            System.out.println("Enter either 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors.");

            int numberGuessed = input.nextInt();

            Random generator = new Random();
            int computerNumber = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (numberGuessed == computerNumber) {
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");
            } else if (numberGuessed == 1 && computerNumber == 2) {
                System.out.println("You lose! I chose paper and paper smothers rock!");
            } else if (numberGuessed == 1 && computerNumber == 3) {
                System.out.println("You win! I chose scissors and rock smashes scissors!");
            } else if (numberGuessed == 2 && computerNumber == 1) {
                System.out.println("You win! I chose rock and paper smothers rock!");
            } else if (numberGuessed == 2 && computerNumber == 3) {
                System.out.println("You lose! I chose scissors and scissors cut paper!");
            } else if (numberGuessed == 3 && computerNumber == 2) {
                System.out.println("You win! I chose paper and scissors cut paper!");
            } else if (numberGuessed == 3 && computerNumber == 1) {
                System.out.println("You lose! I chose rock and rock smashes scissors!");
            } else if (numberGuessed != 1 || numberGuessed != 2 || numberGuessed != 3) {
                System.out.println("Invalid user input.");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It hit me later that I hadn't placed all of the necessary code inside the loop, was kicking myself for that. For some reason though, now when I input 1 the program responds with "Invalid user input." Is there another mistake somewhere in that line? Also, can I ask why you added a blank System.out.println(); towards the end?

Comment: @Anna79 Are you sure about that?? Please try to run the whole code in my answer once again and check if it outputs correctly. For input `1` this program should never return `Invalid user input.`.

Comment: And the blank `System.out.println();` is only for designing purpose or you can say for better readability in console. After each round there will be one blank line. So, it will look good.

Comment: `else {
    System.out.println("Invalid user input. Please enter 1, 2 or 3.");
   }` I've since made changes to the code to use constants and to compile a score, so I can't run yours now. This is the line in question and I've tried it like this, like it was written before in the example and written with <> signs but 1 still gives "Invalid user input." and I have zero idea why ://

Comment: Is there somewhere I could send the full code to you? It's too long for a comment.

Comment: I did find some problems with the if statements repeating but it hasn't affected the invalid user input error: https://pastebin.com/y6kU9S47

Comment: @Anna79 You need to use `else if` for 2nd and 3rd `if` also for solving your particular problem

Answer (score 0):

You set numbers and do 5 rounds on the same data. Move initialization of numberGuessed and computerNumber inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Observe where your input and random number generator is. Think if that will repeat 5 times when your loop runs. Done?

If you haven't observed yet, let me elaborate: your input and random number generator is outside you for loop. That's IT.